# Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS installation failed. says: "GRUB installation failed"

Tags: system-installation, hp, hp-pavilion, grub-efi

The error message is :`the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader the system will not boot`

I'm trying to install on HP pavilion g6-2303 TX using USB.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug. `/pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.9~ubuntu12.04.4+1.99-21ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb` file rename when you burn it in CD/DVD or usb disk to `grub-efi-amd64-signed 1.9~ubuntu12.04.4+1.99-21ubuntu3.10_amd.deb`. As a result installation script can't find the file and failed to install grub. Quick workaround is that(if you burn iso in USB flash drive) go to pool/main/g/grub2-signed(in usb flash disk) and rename the deb file manually (add **64**). Now boot from usb flash drive and run a disk check to be sure.

Comment: I don't have a `/pool`

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing, as Ronshere suggests, is a possibility; however, there's no guarantee that you won't run into the same problem again. Two other options are:

- Run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an emergency Linux disc. With any luck, this will correct the problem.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Prepare the medium and boot with it. With any luck, this will enable you to boot Linux. If this works, check to be sure that your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is mounted at `/boot/efi` and install the Debian-package version of rEFInd. You should then be able to boot to Ubuntu via rEFInd, without using the USB flash drive, CD-R, or GRUB.

If these procedures both fail, post back with details, including the URL that the Boot Repair procedure generated.

Answer (score 0):

First, boot to your USB and let Ubuntu start a live session. You will see an icon on the desktop that says Install Ubuntu on your desktop. Launch (click on) it.

When you get to the screen where it asks you if you want to replace an existing install or install next to it or **Something Else**, choose **Something Else**.

Now you will see a screen that will let you see the hard drive you want to install to. Make sure you choose the correct drive you want to install Ubuntu on! On that screen you will need to first delete any existing partitions so you can start fresh.

Start at the bottom of the listed partitions and right click on each one and choose Delete. After you have done this to all the partitions, click on Apply. When you have deleted everything your drive will show as completely unallocated space! Sometimes some partitions cannot be deleted right away  so delete all you can at first and click Apply, then start over from the bottom until they are all deleted.

Now you want to create the necessary partitions for you to install Ubuntu.

Create the following partitions.

1. a boot partition `/boot` with 250mb of space, choose ext4 for the format.
2. a root partition `/root` with 15000mb of space and ext4 format
3. a swap partition `/swap` with 4096mb of space (it will format to swap)
4. a home partition `/home` with the rest of the space and format it as ext4.

Now just finish the install and it will run beautifully.

Comment: Um... what? Your suggested partition scheme is... wrong. `/root` is **not** the root partition, `/boot` will contain the actual Linux kernels so, if it is on a separate partition (which is not always necessary or a good idea), it should be a lot bigger than your suggestion. The size of swap depends on the hardware... You give no explanation for the numbers you suggest and if people follow this scheme naively they will definitely have problems!